# Postgis Spatial Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to create a query that will return a list of points that do not intersect with a line. For the most part it works great and very fast. However I would like to know how far away the nearest line is.

I have tried to use the `st_distance` function but it is returning null. Does anybody have any tips or guidance to help me solve this?

This is my SQL statement so far:

```sql
SELECT p.objectid, p.voidentifier, p.featuretypecd, p.heightagl, st_distance(p.geom::geography, l.geom::geography), p.geom 
FROM vo_point p 
  LEFT JOIN vo_line l ON ST_Intersects(p.geom, l.geom) 
WHERE l.featureid IS NULL 
  and p.featuretypecd in ('537','538','540','541','542','543','544');
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide a few data samples?

Comment: First of all, st_distance returns null, because your left join is returning all the null records. Also, you are converting all geoms to geography which will slow things down. Can you use geography?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a subquery is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT p.objectid, p.voidentifier, p.featuretypecd, p.heightagl, p.geom,
  (SELECT min(ST_Distance(p.geom::geography, l2.geom::geography)) FROM vo_line l2)
FROM vo_point p 
LEFT JOIN vo_line l ON ST_Intersects(p.geom, l.geom) 
WHERE l.featureid IS NULL 
  AND p.featuretypecd IN ('537','538','540','541','542','543','544');
```

This query should return all records where points and lines intersect, and it will also return the distance to the nearest line.

Comment: Jim, Thank  you for your reply. I am currently running this query and it taking a long time. I have 381980 linestrings and 145020 points. So the subquery is really slowing everything down.

Comment: @SteveWeeks I suspected that too. With large tables this should really take a look time. If you're not dealing with dynamic data: Would be an option for you to calculate these values and store it in a column beforehand?

Comment: Jim, the data is updated on a daily basis. I will let the query run and comment again later if it completes. Thanks for your help and suggestion.

Comment: I think SELECT DISTINCT ON might be quicker than the subquery way, but we probably need to find a way to stop getting the nearest intersecting line...

Answer (score 0):

So after more than an hour I decided to abort and try a different approach.
Instead I created two views:

```
create view pylon_temp as SELECT p.objectid, p.voidentifier, p.featuretypecd, p.heightagl, p.geom
FROM vo_point p LEFT JOIN vo_line l ON ST_Intersects(p.geom, l.geom)
WHERE l.featureid IS NULL and p.featuretypecd in ('537','538','540','541','542','543','544');
```

```
create view pylon_errors as
select p.objectid, p.voidentifier, p.featuretypecd, p.heightagl, min(st_distance(p.geom::geography, l.geom::geography))as distance, p.geom
from pylon_temp p, vo_line l
where st_dwithin(p.geom,l.geom,0.001)
group by p.objectid, p.voidentifier, p.featuretypecd, p.heightagl, p.geom
order by distance desc;
```

It may not be the most elegant way of going about this, but it is very quick and I can use the view in my web app / GIS applications.

Comment: Instead of the group by in your second view you can do select distinct on (p.objectid) objectid (other columns) from pylon_temp p, vo_line l order by p.objectid, st_distance(p.geom::geography, l.geom::geography)

Comment: Also the nearest line might be one that intersects with another point. I don't know if that is an issue.

Comment: @mlinth I tried your approach and it is too slow compared to the 2nd view that I created. It would be nice to optimize the first sql query so that I don't have to create two views though.